# How to run a single test case method in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, xdebug

I am using the cakephp test (php unit test) with xdebug to run the server side code and monitor the output from the terminal rather than using it for validation.
So, every time, i want to run some particular lib/controller/model method from the terminal and see the output, i have to comment out the other test case functions.
I know this might not be the right approach,
but  i want to know, if there is a way, i can build up a wrapper around the cake test, that will take the argument of the method name which i want to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to write a wrapper script

### To run one test method

Use the filter option:

```
-> phpunit --help
PHPUnit 4.4.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>
...
Test Selection Options:

  --filter <pattern>        Filter which tests to run.
```

For example:

```
-> phpunit --debug --filter testValidationDefault tests/TestCase/Model/Table/PostsTableTest.php 
PHPUnit 4.4.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/cakephp.dev/phpunit.xml.dist


Starting test 'App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\PostsTableTest::testValidationDefault'.
I

Time: 130 ms, Memory: 9.75Mb

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Incomplete: 1.     
www-data @ dev [ /var/www/cakephp.dev ]
->
```

Answer (score 3):

To run only one test use the filter option in the cake command line tool:

```
cake test app Model/Post --filter testGetAllPostsByAuthor
```

**Works on CakePhp 2.2**